# Ubunutu 20.04: What is the Ubuntu appropriate method of setting a static IP address?

Tags: networking, 20.04, raspberrypi, static-ip

I am losing my mind with a fresh install of server 20.04 on Pi4.  There is no desktop on this install.  Only a terminal.

I have disabled cloud-init with the following:

```
echo "network: {config: disabled}" > etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
```

and then I rebooted and created `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` with a simple static LAN connection on enp0s3.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses: [192.168.1.3/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [4.2.2.2, 8.8.8.8]
  version: 2
```

When I run `netplan try` it hangs forever.  Is there a more 20.04-appropriate, command line method to disable cloud-init and set a static IP address on 20.04?  I hate to sound like my father but I am beginning to miss the known and loved (traditional?) network tools on Ubuntu.  :-)

**Update:**

After reading the docs and a few useful posts I am now doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

move aside the old cloud yaml file

create a new 10-config.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.3/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Then create the templates and apply the configuration:

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
sudo netplan -d apply           
sudo reboot
```

There are no errors with netplan (now that network manager is installed) but I am unable to login.  I can see with nmap (based upon the MAC address) that the device has not changed ip addresses and is still using a dynamic address.

Comment: The netplan is finicky about indenting. It expects the exact number of spaces, and won't work if you use tab instead of spaces.

Comment: I have a yaml validator.  I will run it through that.  Is the overall approach sound?

Comment: See https://netplan.io

Comment: I've been referencing that page but I may not have formatted my YAML correctly (and am missing a renderer).

Comment: The only way I can get the device to use a static IP address is to edit /boot/firmware/network-config with my netplan information.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration works for me.  After running ip link I see that Pi4 uses eth0 rather than enp0s3.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [192.168.0.50/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.100
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Followed by:

```
sudo netplan --debug generate  # generate the config files
sudo netplan --debug apply     # apply the new configuration
```